# Can't control the order of messages posted to a channel in response to slash commands

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

My bot makes multiple sendMessage requests to a channel in quick succession in response to slash commands and it often ends up posting them in the wrong order.

General workflow:

1. User sends a Slash Command
2. `event.getHook().deferReply()`
3. `event.getHook().editOriginal(...)`
4. `event.getChannel().sendMessage(...)` - zero or more of these

The first `getChannel().sendMessage(...)` occasionally (~30% of the time) will post to the channel before the `getHook().editOriginal(...)`, which confuses my users.
The remaining `getChannel().sendMessage(...)`s will typically post in the correct order from that point on.

I am not utilizing any threading, and running on a single CPU vm, if that matters.

I've tried adding a delay to all the `sendMessage`s, but that seems to make the problem worse and then all the `sendMessage`s get jumbled up out of order.

I've tried avoiding `editOriginal` and just deleting the original reply, but that deletes the user's command text, which also annoys my users.

---

This is what I want it to look like 100% of the time - only looks like this 70% of the time:

[image]

This is what it looks like 30% of the time:

[image]

This is what happens when using multiple `event.getHook().sendMessage(...)` in succession:
[image: fail1]

This is what happens when I do not use `getHook().editOrignal(...)` and go straight to `sendMessage(...)` - the bot will "think" until the event expires in 15min:

[image]

Comment: If you use `event.getHook().sendMessage(...)` they should all arrive in sequence. You can also replace the `editOriginal` with a `sendMessage` since they do the same for `deferReply()`.

Comment: the problem with using `event.gethook().sendMessage()` is that every message sent will appear as a reply to the original message, instead of just a new message to the channel. I've edited my original question to show my differing use of `getHook()` and `getChannel()`

Comment: also, I added a screenshot of what happens when I replace the editOriginal with a sendMessage - the bot appears to hang on "thinking" until the event expires in 15m

Comment: Then you'll have to put all your sendMessage calls inside the callback of editOriginal. However, it is highly recommended to not mix channel messages with interaction messages like you are attempting.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to handle this scenario. Very often the multiple `channel.sendmessage` requests are actually one large block of text that's been split up due to having more than 2000 characters. I suppose the only option then is to delete the original reply that houses the original command text send by the user, and instead just send a message to the channel with the command text. Not ideal, but if it's my only option..